# Magento 2 Move left sidebar Customer menus list to somewhere

Tags: magento2, customer, menu, sidebar

Anyone know how to move left sidebar's Customer menu list to right sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this file

\magento\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

replace to

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Remove the cache and check.

> Note : recommended to override by custom module.

Comment: this only works for `customer\account` how we can do this for all pages like `sales/order/history` and `customer/account/edit`